# N-word counter in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I want to make an N-word counter but I don't really know how

Here's the code:

```
@client.event
async def on:message(msg):
  if 'N-word here' in msg.content:
    await msg.channel.send("Ok this guy decided to be racist.\nN-Words: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be to store a global variable with a counter:

```py
BADGER_COUNT = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'badger' in msg.content.lower():
        global BADGER_COUNT
        BADGER_COUNT += 1
        await msg.channel.send(f"Badgers? BADGERS?! We don't need {BADGER_COUNT} stinkin' BADGERS!")
```

If you wanted to keep track of who sent how many such messages, you can use a dictionary that corresponds user IDs to counters:

```py
MEOW_COUNTERS = dict()
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'meow' in msg.content.lower():
        MEOW_COUNTERS[msg.author.id] = MEOW_COUNTERS.get(msg.author.id, 0) + 1
        await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author} has meowed {MEOW_COUNTERS[msg.author.id]} times already!")
```

Keep in mind that both of these approaches will only keep count as long as the program is running, and they will reset when it restarts. To avoid that you might want to store this to a file, or use some other persistence method.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variable that you increment each time:

```py
counter = 0 
@client.event
async def on:message(msg):
  if 'N-word here' in msg.content:
    counter += 1 # Add one to the counter
    await msg.channel.send(f"Ok this guy decided to be racist.\nN-Words: {counter}") # Include the counter in the message
```